# How to configure Checkmarx through jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, checkmarx

I am trying to configure checkmarx through Jenkins file previously the checkmarx scripts was reading from groovy file which is globally configured.

This is how my jenkinsfile looks

```
stage('Code Scanning') {
      parallel {
        stage('Static Code Analysis') {
          steps {
            step([$class: 'CxScanBuilder',
                    comment: '',
                    credentialsId: '',
                    excludeFolders: '.helmignore, build, templates, javadocs, javadoc, 
                                   dist, node_modules, WMSRegistryReader.java, 
                                   BlowfishEncryptionStrategy.java, BlowfishUtils.java',
                    excludeOpenSourceFolders: '',
                    exclusionsSetting: 'global',
                    failBuildOnNewResults: false,
                    failBuildOnNewSeverity: 'MEDIUM',
                    filterPattern: '''!**/_cvs/**/*, !Checkmarx/Reports/*.*''',
                    fullScanCycle: 10,
                    groupId: '0de2e46c-8410-478a-85b9-b5dce83f8ecb',
                    includeOpenSourceFolders: '',
                    osaArchiveIncludePatterns: '*.zip, *.war, *.ear, *.tgz',
                    osaInstallBeforeScan: false,
                    password: '{}',
                    preset: '36',
                    projectName: "${APP_NAME}",
                    sastEnabled: true,
                    serverUrl: 'https://checkmarx.abc.com',
                    sourceEncoding: '1',
                    username: '',
                    vulnerabilityThresholdResult: 'FAILURE',
                    waitForResultsEnabled: true])
          }
        }
        stage('Open Source Compliance') {
          steps {
            blackduck([appName: "${APP_NAME}", appDomain: "${APP_DOMAIN}", branchName: 
            "master"])
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But the Build is considering global configuration done from jenkins-> Configuration setting instead of service `jenkinsfile`

Is there any syntax issue in my `jenkinsfile` or anything I'm missing here.

Comment: The Checkmarx knowledge as been suficient for me : See https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/11337790/CxSAST+Jenkins+Plugin

Answer (score 2):

Can't find documentation for it but I have set

```
exclusionsSetting: '',
```

Instead of

```
exclusionsSetting: 'global',
```

In order to override global Checkmarx settings

Comment: Worked wonders for me.

Answer (score 0):

I choose free style rather then going for pipeline job in jenkins.
Here is how I configured even without checkmarx plugin.

First generate a token using below command
runCxConsole.cmd GenerateToken -v -CxUser username -CxPassword admin -CxServer http://localhost

Congfiure below lines of code in Build --> Execute Shell

```
Jenkins Script 
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
export CHECKMARX_HOME=/<checkmarx plugin path>/CxConsolePlugin-8.90.2
echo ${WORKSPACE}
echo $CX_PROJECT_NAME
mkdir ${WORKSPACE}/cxReports
export CHECKMARX_REPORTS_HOME=${WORKSPACE}/cxReports
echo $CHECKMARX_REPORTS_HOME

$CHECKMARX_HOME/runCxConsole.sh Scan -v -CxServer <checkmarx server details> -ProjectName "<project anme>" -cxToken <token> -locationtype folder -locationpath "${WORKSPACE}" -preset "Default Checkamrx" -reportcsv $CHECKMARX_REPORTS_HOME/$CX_PROJECT_NAME.csv -ReportPDF $CHECKMARX_REPORTS_HOME/$CX_PROJECT_NAME.pdf
```

Note:Always use token for authentication with the server instead hard coding the username and password in the CLI command.

For more information you can visit https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/222232891/Authentication+Login+to+the+CLI